# Always select the first sheet in Excel

Tags: excel, vb.net, datagridview

Hello and Good Morning,

I have a piece of code here that imports an excel file and populate it in datagridview and here it is.

```
Dim conn As OleDbConnection

        Dim dts As DataSet
        Dim excel As String
        Dim OpenFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog

        OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
        OpenFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|XLS Files (*.xls)|*xls"
        If (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
            Dim fi As New FileInfo(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
            Dim FileName As String = OpenFileDialog.FileName
            excel = fi.FullName
            conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';")
            conn.Open()
            Dim myTableName = conn.GetSchema("Tables").Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME")

            Dim MyCommand As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(String.Format("Select F3 as ItemCode,F4 as Description,F6 as RequestedQty,F9 as Remarks,F11 as Tag  From [Official Transmittal Form$]", myTableName), conn)
            dts = New DataSet
            MyCommand.Fill(dts, 13, 878, "MyTable")
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dts
            DataGridView1.DataMember = "MyTable"
            conn.Close()
            '  DataGridView1.Columns(7).ValueType = GetType(Double)
            '  DataGridView1.Columns(7).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
            '  DataGridView1.Columns(9).ValueType = GetType(Double)
            '  DataGridView1.Columns(9).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
            '  DataGridView1.Columns(10).ValueType = GetType(Double)
            '  DataGridView1.Columns(10).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
            '  DataGridView1.Columns(11).ValueType = GetType(Double)
            '  DataGridView1.Columns(11).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
            '  DataGridView1.Columns(12).ValueType = GetType(Double)
            '  DataGridView1.Columns(12).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
        End If
```

but then my problem here is the word `Official Transmittal Form` from the code above. My Question is how can i import only the first sheet? regardless of what would be the sheet name. There must be an instances that the sheetname might change all i want is to import the first sheet. what would be the modification in my program?

I tried this code but it has an error

here is the code

```
 Dim conn As OleDbConnection

        Dim dts As DataSet
        Dim excel As String
        Dim OpenFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog

        OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
        OpenFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|XLS Files (*.xls)|*xls"
        If (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
            Dim fi As New FileInfo(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
            Dim FileName As String = OpenFileDialog.FileName
            Dim xlApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
            Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
            Dim SheetName As String = xlWorkBook.Worksheets(0).Name.ToString
            excel = fi.FullName
            conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';")
            conn.Open()
            Dim myTableName = conn.GetSchema("Tables").Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME")

            Dim MyCommand As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(String.Format("Select F3 as ItemCode,F4 as Description,F6 as RequestedQty,F9 as Remarks,F11 as Tag  From [" & SheetName & "$]", myTableName), conn)
            dts = New DataSet
            MyCommand.Fill(dts, 13, 878, "MyTable")
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dts
            DataGridView1.DataMember = "MyTable"
            conn.Close()
            '  DataGridView1.Columns(7).ValueType = GetType(Double)
            '  DataGridView1.Columns(7).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
            '  DataGridView1.Columns(9).ValueType = GetType(Double)
            '  DataGridView1.Columns(9).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
            '  DataGridView1.Columns(10).ValueType = GetType(Double)
            '  DataGridView1.Columns(10).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
            '  DataGridView1.Columns(11).ValueType = GetType(Double)
            '  DataGridView1.Columns(11).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
            '  DataGridView1.Columns(12).ValueType = GetType(Double)
            '  DataGridView1.Columns(12).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
        End If
```

and here is the error

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkbookClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

TYSM
```

Comment: So the problem here is you want to get the first worksheet's record without knowing it's sheet name?

Comment: @CrushSundae yes sir. Hello its you again :D

Comment: Based on my example i can only import `Official Transmittal Form` what if the name changes?

Comment: @CrushSundae sir can i ask you something?

Comment: What? Go ahead.

Comment: Actually sir its a new post, would you mind if i transfer you to that?

Comment: Here it is the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886695/series-number-in-every-page-header-in-excel-and-instead-1-turn-1-to-a-and-so-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the internet says, `OLEDB` does not preserve the index and ordering of the worksheets in Excel.

If you're that desperate, you can use this workaround:

```
Dim xlApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workook= xlApp.Workbooks.Open(OpenFileDialog.FileName)

Dim SheetName As String = xlWorkBook.Worksheets(1).Name.ToString
```

You now have the name of your first sheet then concatenate it with your query.

```
Dim MyCommand As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(String.Format("Select F3 as ItemCode,F4 as Description,F6 as RequestedQty,F9 as Remarks,F11 as Tag  From [" & SheetName & "$]", myTableName), conn)
```

Comment: sir on the part of Dim sheetname it has an error of ---> Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))

Comment: We both have the same thoughts i change it to 1 and now it works like a charm TYSSSSSM :D

Comment: TYSM for being always there to assist me (teary eyes)

Comment: It just happened that I already went there. Anyways, I'm glad I can be of help to somebody. But no homo, dude :)

Comment: Just kidding men anyway Thank you so much your awesome

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed it was already accepted. Upvote is optional. :)

Comment: No need sir when it comes to your answers in my question there will accept and upvote :D

Answer (score 0):

import sheet to tow DataGridView .
the first DataGridView1 for all data . viable must be false .
the second DataGridView2 for the first sheet name.viable must be true .
you can use code :

```
  Try
        DataG1.Rows.Clear()
        Total2.Text = "0"
        ProgressBar1.Visible = True
        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection : ProgressBar1.Value = 10
        Dim dataSet As System.Data.DataSet : ProgressBar1.Value = 20
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter : ProgressBar1.Value = 30
        Dim path As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Exle.xlsx")
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection) : ProgressBar1.Value = 50
        dataSet = New System.Data.DataSet : ProgressBar1.Value = 60
        MyCommand.Fill(dataSet) : ProgressBar1.Value = 70
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0) : ProgressBar1.Value = 80
        MyConnection.Close() : ProgressBar1.Value = 100
        ProgressBar1.Visible = False
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        ProgressBar1.Visible = True
        Dim I As Integer : ProgressBar1.Value = 10
        For I = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2 : ProgressBar1.Value = 50
            Dim ItemsName As DataGridViewTextBoxCell = DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(0)
            Dim ItemsPrice As DataGridViewTextBoxCell = DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(1)
            DataG1.Rows.Add(False, "", "", ItemsName.Value, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ItemsPrice.Value)
        Next : ProgressBar1.Value = 100
        ProgressBar1.Visible = False
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        Total2.Text = DataG1.RowCount - 1
    Catch ex As Exception
        ProgressBar1.Visible = False
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
```

Comment: Please elaborate sir I cant understand it :( i check your code but it seems that the code will import sheet1 what if i change the name of sheet1? it will have an  error

Comment: change the name to your sheet name and put the Exle in the same project folder .

Comment: Sir i think that would not be advisable because the excel file will come to the user and i dont know where do they get it and sir the system must import the excel file no matter whats the name of sheet but based on your code it will import only "sheet1" what if i change "sheet1" do i need to change the code to.

Comment: OK ... you can use OpenFileDialog to get the exel . but the sheet must be sheet1 .